# Could not find a part of the path 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\oobe\\info\\Backgrounds

Tags: c#, .net, windows-7

I'm trying to list all files on Windows 7 under C:\Windows\System32\oobe\info\Backgrounds by calling the folowing:

```
const string logonScreenBackgroundPath = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\oobe\\info\\Backgrounds";
DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(logonScreenBackgroundPath);
string[] backgroundFiles = Directory.GetFiles(logonScreenBackgroundPath);
```

However I get an exception on the GetFiles call: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Windows\System32\oobe\info\Backgrounds

I verified the folder exists and has files, I cd to it on the command prompt and all is well, but the c# call fails.

Calling GetFiles on C:\Windows\System32\oobe\ works fine though.  Nothing different as far as folder attributes go between \oobe and \info.

After further investigation this looks like a 64-bit issue.  When I build my project for "AnyCpu" the folder is found with no issues.  Problem is my project has to compile for x86 and not AnyCpu due to dependencies.

SOLUTION:
Looks like this is a known issue and MS has issued a hotfix for it.  The problem is due to filesystem redirection.

I now disable redirection on the calling thread with the following:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection(ref IntPtr ptr);

IntPtr ptr = new IntPtr();
bool isWow64FsRedirectionDisabled = Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection(ref ptr);
```

Comment: I have very little knowledge of Window's permissions structure but is the folder readable by all users? Under what permissions does your application run at?

Comment: Your string only has single \ characters in it. Typo?

Comment: That was just a typo when copying my code to this web form, the backslashed are escaped properly

Comment: @user577240  Get the DirectoryInfo of info\ and do a GetDirectories() it might give you a clue.

Comment: @terationx I listed directories under \oobe and it's only showing en-US.  But \oobe also has a \info subfolder which is not showing for some reason.

Comment: As someone mentioned below, you can avoid having to escape `\\​` all your slashes using the `@` character:  `@"C:\Windows\System32\oobe\info\Backgrounds"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am pretty sure your problem is related to [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942589) which describes what's wrong and how to fix the problem. There is a hotfix available from the site that you can install and should fix your issue. I hope this helps!

Comment: That's the problem.  Instead of applying the hotfix as the article suggests, I instead disable filesystem redirection by calling:       [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection(ref IntPtr ptr);

Comment: Dead link + no way to find it = not useful

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer from Icemanind, if you're compiling a .net application, a solution that worked for us is to change your platform target (from AnyCPU) to x64.

No need to install a hotfix.